# Get a web page with print stylesheets?

Tags: printing, html, css

Is there a way to fetch a website with print stylesheets enabled, i.e. get the HTML code that is used to create a printed page?

Comment: If a web page has a print stylesheet enabled, you can view it with your browser's print preview command, or print it with the browser's print command. I do this with my hobby website, [Freelance Traveller](https://www.freelancetraveller.com) - browse down to an article, then look at the print preview or print the article.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get the actual HTML sourcecode for the print preview. Thanks

Comment: If it's using a print stylesheet, it's the same HTML for both. You should do some research into how stylesheets work with web pages.

Comment: I figured the responsible line on your page is
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
but this command is not explicitly included in other pages like youtube.com. How do they do it?

Comment: Sometimes, the print style info is done with media queries in the CSS. You should do some serious digging into CSS. Many major sites "style" things with ECMAScript manipulation of the DOM, which gives them quite a bit more flexibility, at the cost of having to fine-tune for every browser engine out there, or explicitly saying "If you're using BogusBrowser, tough noogies; we break that one."